# i have problem in my react app he was working but now give me this error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

node:internal/buffer:961
super(bufferOrLength, byteOffset, length);
^

RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed
at new ArrayBuffer ()
at new Uint8Array ()
at new FastBuffer (node:internal/buffer:961:5)
at createUnsafeBuffer (node:internal/buffer:1064:12)
at Function.allocUnsafeSlow (node:buffer:397:10)
at read (C:\Users\nenab\Desktop\json\react project\Archi\midou\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\serialization\FileMiddleware.js:597:32)
at C:\Users\nenab\Desktop\json\react project\Archi\midou\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\serialization\FileMiddleware.js:657:7
at C:\Users\nenab\Desktop\json\react project\Archi\midou\frontend\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:362:16
at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:23)

Node.js v18.15.0

I don't try anything

Comment: You seem to be out of memory. Try restarting your computer to begin with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved my problem,

1. uninstall nodejs
2. reinstall nodejs (from web)

"issue is occur when you install 32 bit node js  on 64 bit system.
You can check using `node -p "process.arch"`
"

Comment: Sumit Kumar, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)